# Getting git smudge filter to work in Ubuntu

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a git smudge filter to work in ubuntu, as described in this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs

The goal is to convert spaces to tabs on checkout.

In my .gitconfig I have this entry:

```
[filter "tabspace"]
    smudge = unexpand --tabs=4 --first-only
    clean = expand --tabs=4 --initial
```

As an example, consider the lxqt-panel repository which uses spaces for indentation: https://github.com/lxde/lxqt-panel

In `lxqt-panel/.git/info/attributes`, I enabled the tabspace filter:

```
*.cpp   filter=tabspace
*.h     filter=tabspace
```

According to the Stackoverflow Answer various online sources, running `git checkout HEAD -- **` should now convert all spaces to tabs. However, in my case git seems to ignore these settings completely; running `unexpand` manually works though.

What am I missing here?

I'm using git 2.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout HEAD -- **` will only convert files that have changes. Unchanged files will not be touched, that's why nothing is replaced in them. To force updating all files, you could remove them and then reset. But make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes, because they will be lost. For example you could do this:

```
git rm -r .
git reset --hard
```

Or, if you prefer, you could replace only all `.h` and `.cpp` files with:

```
rm **/*.{h,cpp}
git checkout .
```